# Excel VBA Union returning original range

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue when trying to use Union(Range, Range). I am trying to copy certain rows from one worksheet and paste them in a new file. My issue is that the Union isn't adding on more rows to the range; it returns the original range. If I flip the order of the parameters, it returns only the .Rows(i + 1) row. My test data has 2 rows that it should copy. The row count at the end is 1. What am I doing wrong?!

```
Dim lastRow, i As Long
Dim CopyRange As Range
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Rows.count

With Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        Dim endTime As Date
        endTime = DateValue(Trim(.Range("E" & i).Value))
        If endTime = Date - 1 Then
            If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                Set CopyRange = .Rows(i + 1)
            Else
                Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, .Rows(i + 1))
            End If


        End If
    Next
End With

CopyRange.Copy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `CopyRange` contains a number of separate ranges (areas). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.areas%28v=office.11%29.ASPX) for more information. 
When you make `Union` operation with separate rows (I mean that there is another row beetween them) it doesen't actually add Row, but add new Area. So, if you add `MsgBox CopyRange.Areas.Count`, you will see count of areas (if you will add `MsgBox CopyRange.Rows.Count` it will get you uncorrect result in case of many areas - it will get count of rows in first area). 
As a conclusion, your code works well for me, and should works well for you. You can add `CopyRange.Select` line before `CopyRange.Copy` and set breakpoint on this line. You will see that union works well

Comment: The issue in my code was that I iterated through the rows of CopyRange later, which I left out here. With your help I change this up to work. Thank you very much.